# How to add/remove class on elements from ().load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a login form in my home page, where if user logs in, the form will disappear, I did this in the javascript. Now I used a ().load method on my other pages so that they would have the same header and footer just like my home page.

What Im trying to achieve now is that the login form will stay hidden in my other pages while the user is still logged in.

So far I tried including the javascript file through out the other pages but the form would reappear as if the user is not logged in.

I used a .load method() so I can used my headers and footers on different pages, my login form in inside the header but, when user is logged in the form should disappear :

```
$( "#import-headerContainer" ).load( "index.html #headerContainer" );
$( "#import-header" ).load( "index.html #header" );
```

I used local storage variable to check if user is logged in:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("logged") !== null) {
            $('.login-info').removeClass('login-hide');
            $("#header-content").addClass('login-hide');
```

This is working in the home page header but not the other pages.

Comment: show more code samples, unclear what's wrong

Comment: I've edited my original question...

Comment: Are all your pages using the same protocol..?  If the home page is using HTTPS and the others are using HTTP, the localstorage won't be accessible from them if the protocols are different.

Comment: @BizzyBob im still currently hosting it locally

Comment: are you using dot net or java.dot net has masterpage .. which uses common header accross the appliication